# HomeBrew messes up Python installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, homebrew

Previously, I had this:

```
$ python # version 2.7.x
$ python3 # version 3.6.x
```

This was working fine. I made the idiotic mistake of trying fix something that wasn't broken and I ran these:

```
brew install python@2
brew install python@3
```

I was thinking that this would do this:

```
$ python2 # version 2.7.x
$ python3 # version 3.6.x
```

but actually what it did was:

```
$ python2 # doesn't exist, damnit
$ python # version 3.6.x
```

The end result I am looking for:

```
$ python # version 2.7.x
$ python2 # version 2.7.x
$ python3 # version 3.6.x
```

in fact, it would be nice to toggle `$python` between version 2/3 if possible. How can I do this on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

I just did

```
brew uninstall python@2
brew uninstall python@3
```

and then re-ran

```
brew install python@3
```

now:

```
 python --version # => 2.7.x
```

and

```
python3 --version # => 3.6.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 is the default program in Mac OS and should not be removed. You can set python3 as default by creating an alias - open `~/.bash_profile` file and add `alias python='python3'`.

Next time when you type `python`, python3 will be picked up instead of python 2.7.